# IOS missing something to switches reference or something?

Tags: ios, swift

So my app is a basic music library in which when a user clicks on the album, the view switches to a reference id and that id correlates with the album just giving it basic info like on the artist and songs and whatnot. Something is missing to the point when I run the app nothing is happening at all or the app crashes.

```
  var names=[String]()
var identities = [String]()


var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad(){

    names = ["That's The Spirit", "Chocolate Starfish and the Hot Dog Flavored Water", "IOWA"]



}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)-> Int{

    return names.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)-> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    cell?.textLabel!.text = names [indexPath.row]

    return cell!

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create an identities in the viewDidload
and have those refernce in the viewcontroller.
ex. Identities = ["a", "b"]

Comment: Yeah that was the issue i forgot to add that and give the views identities

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to check for the cell being nil, and creating a new UITableViewCell if it is.